# How to access the Doctrine replace() method?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am doing my first project with Symfony2 + Doctrine, and currently trying to implement [replacing records](http://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/component-overview.html#replacing-records). However when I try to call

```
    $em->save($product);
```

or

```
    $em->replace($product);
```

(instead of)

```
    $em->persist($product);
```

I get fatal errors. So I started digging around to try to find the persist() method so I could see what other methods were available. I searched the entire contents of the vendors/doctrine directory and could not find any references to the persist or flush methods. Where the heck are these located? I tried following the code but quickly got lost.

So the main question: How can I do a replace() with doctrine in Symfony2?

Sub-question: Where are the persist() and flush() methods? Not being able to find them is frustrating in itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that Doctrine's `replace()` method is supported in Symfony, or at least it is not accessible through EntityManager.

If you need to update your existing entity, then you can simply do it as described here - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#updating-an-object.

As for `persist()` and `flush()` methods - you can find them in `vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/ObjectManager.php`

Comment: He didn't ask how to update. He asked how to replace. They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Incase somebody else is wondering, try looking into:

```
$em = $service->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
$entity = $em->merge($entity);
$em->flush();
```

From the [docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities), `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::merge()`:

> Merges the state of a detached entity into the persistence context of
>   this EntityManager and returns the managed copy of the entity. The
>   entity passed to merge will not become associated/managed with this
>   EntityManager.

Should do the trick for you.

Comment: I think this only works with entities that have an ID. You can't `INSERT IGNORE` or `REPLACE` based on unique key.